# Find the matrix representation

Tags: matrices

The question I'm stuck on asks: Find the matrix representation of the differential operator D acting on the space of
polynomials of degree at most $3$ with basis $(3, 1 + x, x − x^
2
, 1 + x^
3)$, onto the space of
polynomials of degree at most $3$ with basis $(1 + x, 1 − x, 1 + x^
2)$

I have the answer but I have no idea where to start with this problem. If someone could lead me in the right direction or link me to some resources that would be great

Comment: First of all, the second basis only spans the polynomials of degree at most $2$, hence your $D$ is defined to map onto quadratic polynomials (which is reasonable, since differentiation lowers the degree).

Answer (score 0):

Recall that the matrix representation $A$ of a linear map $T \colon V \to W$ with repsect to bases $(b_i)$ of $V$ and $(c_j)$ of $W$ is defined by the property

> $$ T(b_i) = \sum_{j} a_{ji}c_j $$
>   That is: The representation of the image of the $i$-th basis vector of $V$ forms the $i$-th column of $A$.

Now let's start:
\begin{align*}
  D(3) &= 0\\
       &= 0 \cdot (1+x) + 0 \cdot (1-x) + 0 \cdot (1+x^2)\\
  D(1+x)&= 1\\
       &= \frac 12 \cdot (1+x) + \frac 12 \cdot (1-x) + 0 \cdot (1+x^2)\\
  D(x-x^2) &= 1-2x\\
       &= -\frac 12 (1+x) + \frac 32 \cdot (1-x) + 0 \cdot (1+x^2)\\
  D(1 + x^3) &= 3x^2\\
       &= -\frac 32(1+ x) - \frac 32(1-x)    + 3 \cdot (1+x^2)
\end{align*}
Hence
$$ A = \begin{pmatrix}
            0 & \frac 12 & -\frac 12 & -\frac 32\\
            0 & \frac 12 & \frac 32 & - \frac 32\\
            0 &  0       & 0        & 3
       \end{pmatrix}
    $$

Answer (score 0):

So, if you have experience with calculus then you know beforehand that the differential operator is a linear operation (because $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}(f(x)+kg(x))=f'(x)+kg'(x)$).  So it makes sense we could represent it with a matrix/linear transformation.

How would we find that transformation?  A linear transformation over some vector space is uniquely determined by how it acts on each basis element.  So, if we call your basis elements in the domain $v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4$, and in the codomain $w_1,w_2,w_3$, then saying that $D(v_1)=0$ (derivative of a constant is zero), $D(v_2)=aw_1+bw_2+cw_3$ (derivative of $x+1=1$.  Find $a,b,c$ to express this in terms of your basis vectors).  Do this for all your basis vectors.

Once you have how $D(v_i)$ behaves (for any basis vector $v_i$), your matrix is just:
\begin{align}
D&=
\begin{pmatrix}
\uparrow&\uparrow&\uparrow&\uparrow\\
D(v_1)&D(v_2)&D(v_3)&D(v_4) \\
\downarrow&\downarrow&\downarrow&\downarrow
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}

Where that matrix means that you "put" the vectors in vertically, with $w_1$ at the top.

To see why this is the case, imagine we have that matrix.  Let's try finding what $Dv_1$ is.  Recall, in the basis $v$, $v_1=(1,0,0,0)$.  Also, the notation $D(v_1)_1$ means the first component of $D(v_1)$.
\begin{align}
Dv_1=&
\begin{pmatrix}
(Dv_1)_1&(Dv_2)_1&(Dv_3)_1&(Dv_4)_1\\
(Dv_1)_2&(Dv_2)_2&(Dv_3)_2&(Dv_4)_2\\
(Dv_1)_3&(Dv_2)_3&(Dv_3)_2&(Dv_4)_3
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
1\\0\\0\\0
\end{pmatrix} \\
&=(Dv_1)_1+(Dv_1)_2+(Dv_1)_3
\end{align}
So, we've recovered $Dv_1$, which is what we wanted to do.

You can verify this works for any $v_i$.  And as it works for any $v_i$, it works for any linear combination of $v_i$, which is any element of your vector space.

That process of finding how some transformation works on your basis vectors (in the correct basis for the domain and codomain), then putting the $T(v_i)$ (how you calculate it acts on the basis vectors) "vertically" into a matrix works in general, so it's useful to remember.